# Cannot find the match from inherit

Tags: java, inheritance

In java i have a question for you.

I have Product class and TV class. TV class is inherit from Product. And I have also Store Class.

Product class has variables and its own findMatch method,
TV class has own variables and its own findMatch method,
Store class has ArrayList and findProduct method

In driver class i have add some products,creating objects and add them to ArrayList. And try to findMatch method if the attributues are in TV class, it finds. But the attribute which i want to find is in the Product class (for example brand) it could not find it.
What is wrong with these code, I couldn solve it.

```
public class Product
{

    private String barcode;
    private String brand;
    private String manufactureYear;
    private int price;
    private int yearOfGuarantee;
    private int displaySize;


    //constructor and set & get methods here


    public boolean findMatch(String keyword)
    {
        return getBarcode().equals(keyword) ||
                        getBrand().equals(keyword) ||
            getManufactureYear().equals(keyword)
                     || Integer.toString(getPrice()).equals(keyword)
             || Integer.toString(getYearOfGuarantee()).equals(keyword)
                     ||Integer.toString(getDisplaySize()).equals(keyword);  
    }   
}



public class TV extends Product
{

    private String type;
    private String resolution;


    //constructor and set&get methods here

    public boolean findMatch(String keyword)
    {
        super.findMatch(keyword);
        return getType().equals(keyword) || getResolution().equals(keyword);
    }
}


public class Store 
{

    ArrayList<Product>pList=new ArrayList<>();


    public void findProduct(String keyword)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<pList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(pList.get(i).findMatch(keyword)==true)
            {
                System.out.println(pList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: not only TV objects, I have PC and SmarthPhone objects and they also have findMatch method. When I try to call findMatch method using TV class' attributes (type and resolution) it finds. But it could not find the attributes from inherit class.

Answer (score 1):

In your `TV` `findMatch` method you call the parent version of the method but do nothing with the value returned:

```
public boolean findMatch(String keyword)
{
    super.findMatch(keyword);
    return getType().equals(keyword) || getResolution().equals(keyword);
}
```

You probably want something like:

```
public boolean findMatch(String keyword)
{
    return super.findMatch(keyword) || getType().equals(keyword) || getResolution().equals(keyword);
}
```